# "Les races historiques ayant perdu le sens de l’histoire" (Les Misérables)

Tags: sens, expressions, vocabulaire

Que signifie cette phrase dans ce contexte :

> Rien dans l’histoire n’a ressemblé à ce quart d’heure qui commence à 1814 et qui se termine vers 1820 à l’avénement de M. de Villèle, l’homme pratique de la droite. Ces six années furent un moment extraordinaire ; à la fois brillant et morne, riant et sombre, éclairé comme par le rayonnement de l’aube et tout couvert en même temps des ténèbres des grandes catastrophes qui emplissaient encore l’horizon et s’enfonçaient lentement dans le passé. Il y eut là, dans cette lumière et dans cette ombre, tout un petit monde nouveau et vieux, bouffon et triste, juvénile et sénile, se frottant les yeux ; rien ne ressemble au réveil comme le retour ; groupe qui regardait la France avec humeur et que la France regardait avec ironie ; de bons vieux hiboux marquis plein les rues, les revenus et les revenants, des « ci-devant » stupéfaits de tout, de braves et nobles gentilshommes souriant d’être en France et en pleurant aussi, ravis de revoir leur patrie, désespérés de ne plus retrouver leur monarchie ; la noblesse des croisades conspuant la noblesse de l’empire, c’est-à-dire la noblesse de l’épée ; **les races historiques ayant perdu le sens de l’histoire** ; les fils des compagnons de Charlemagne dédaignant les compagnons de Napoléon.

Source: [Les Misérables — Tome III : Marius (1862)](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Les_Mis%C3%A9rables/Tome_3/Livre_3/03)

Answer (score 3):

Il suffit de lire autour pour comprendre le sens.

Les *races historiques* ici sont les familles de la noblesse d'épée. Les Vermandois, les Bouillon, les Monfort... qui avaient le sens de l'Histoire, qui ont *fait* l'Histoire de France. Bien sûr aussi les Capet... Qui ont perdu le sens de l'Histoire au sens où elles ne suivent pas le sens de l'Histoire porté par Napoléon.

<sub>NDaCOSwt : Je pense qu'Audiard aurait résumé tout ce passage ainsi... : *"Enfin, on peut pas demander plus aux frères Volfoni qu'aux fils de Charlemagne."* ;-)</sub>

Comment: Oui, on retrouve ce sens de *race* dans l'expression *fin de race*.

Comment: @jlliagre : C'est effectivement le même à, je crois, une nuance près. Je n'ai jamais entendu l'expression que tu mentionnes autrement qu'en mauvaise part. Donc oui, c'est le même sens, la charge péjorative en moins dans l'usage qu'en fait VH.

Comment: Ça veut dire quoi 'Le sens de l'Histoire' ? Que signifie le mot 'sens' dans ce contexte ?

Answer (score -3):

Par « race historique » on doit comprendre une race telle qu'elle a été reconnue par l'historien en des temps relativement reculés et qui jusqu'à no jours n'a pas subit les adultérations dues aux mélanges raciaux ; « avoir perdu le sens de l'histoire » doit se comprendre, je pense, en rapport avec l'histoire même de la race historique ; ce qui est dit est que la race (historique) a perdu conscience de son identité historique, de son unité jusqu'alors peu affectée par les autres civilisations ; par exemple si l'on prend l'exemple de la race des juifs modernes, on peut dire que les juifs d'Israël tout au contraire d'avoir perdu leur sens de leur histoire  en tant que race historique, l'ont ré-affirmé, l'ont renforcé ; si l'on considère le reste de la diaspora juive à travers le monde, force est de conclure qu'il existe toujours dans cette communauté un sens très prononcé de la race historique, mais il est loin d'être aussi pur : les mariages interraciaux sont admis et chose assez courante, et une volonté de promouvoir la race ne va pas jusqu'au point de partager l'idéal de ralliement qui motive les israélites d'Israël.